# XmlResourceParser changes text attribute to floating point number

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.0

After the latest Android Studio 3.0 and android update 27.0.1 the XmlResourceParser suddenly reads text attributes containing serial numbers with '.' separators sometimes as floating point numbers, even rounding them off.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<article number="3211005.148">
```

when read with:

```
String number = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "number");
```

then number is: "3211005.2".

"001" changes to "1", but "1293.010" remains "1293.010".

The code has worked well for years. It seems like some "intelligent" resource compilation is doing the damage. Is there anyway to prevent this conversion?

Comment: Windows 10, if that matters.

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem. Did you get a solution?

Comment: @Chen XIng No solution other than changing the attribute into an xml tag/item: <number>3211005.148</number>